# Integrate Windows Azure Active Directory Bearer Authentication at run time

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, bearer-token

Currently, I am integrating Azure Active Directory into my .NET Web API using following code:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientId"],
        Tenant = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureTenant"]
    }
});
```

The audience and tenant were set in web.config file. 
I can get the token correctly and users can log in using their azure AD account. 
However, I moved the audience and tenant to database to allow users to change the settings and disable/enable azure login by UI instead of changing the setting in web.config. 
The above code was changed to:

```
var azureSetting = db.GetAzureSetting();
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = azureSetting.AzureClientId,
        Tenant = azureSetting.AzureTenant
    }
});
```

When the app first starts, there is no config in the database because users do not enter the config yet. Then users go to azure config screen, enter the correct *Client Id, Tenant, Client Secret*. But users can not log in using azure AD user. 
Can anyone explain this case for me?
Is there any way to save azure config in db instead of web.config?

Comment: Turn your Azure AD as multi tenant and add custom logic to check whether tokens comes from tenant-id which stores in database

Comment: My problem is user can change Azure config at runtime after the application start up, however the UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication does not read the change from user. It still use the first configs from StartUp.Auth.cs

Comment: Could you please provide sample for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the post works when web API start  and we can’t change configuration runtime , if you want to enable users change the audience and tenant dynamically, you could handle token validation yourself . You could use [JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate the token after your api app get the access token , code below is for your reference :

```
    public JwtSecurityToken Validate(string token)
    {
        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";

        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint);

        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidAudience = "https://testbasic1.onmicrosoft.com/TodoListService", //your value from database


            IssuerSigningTokens = config.SigningTokens,
            ValidateLifetime = false
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        SecurityToken jwt;

        var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);

        return jwt as JwtSecurityToken;
    }
```

This handler helps you verify the signature of the token to ensure the token was issued by Azure Active Directory,and also verify the claims in the token based on the business logic,in your scenario,you need to confirm audience and tenant.

In you web api app , you could register custom TokenValidationHandler in Global.asax :

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenValidationHandler());
```

You could click [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs) for code sample , you could modify your code to check whether tokens comes from tenant-id which stores in database .

Comment: Hi, your solution works fine with validating login using Azure Cloud.
However, my app support both Azure Cloud and local account login, when add the validation code, it will validate all tokens from both Azure Cloud and local login. 
Is there any way to apply the token validation for only token from Azure Cloud?

Comment: You could check the issuer of the access token , form azure ad 1.0 , the issuer is like :  https:// sts.windows.net/{tenant}/ .You could use below code to get issuer from a access token :  var jwtTokenClaims = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtToken);
            var issuer = jwtTokenClaims.Issuer;